# Can we doubt the existence of our thoughts and feelings? How?

Tags: metaphysics, descartes, bertrand-russell

I'm reading Russell's "The problems of philosophy" and he says that the only thing we can be certain about is the existence of our "Sense-data" which are mainly our thoughts and emotions. I wonder if there is some good argument against the certainty of it.

Comment: There are some very strong arguments against but they go much wider and deep into metaphysics so are difficult to state here. Russell was obviously not a fan of Kant and he dismisses Bradley with a hand-waive. For another view try Bradley's metaphysical essay 'Appearance and Reality'.